# Talk to an Azure Cognitive services bot with a phone

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-bot-service, skype-bots

I created an Azure bot with cognitive services, and enabled the direct speech client and skype channels. 
I can talk to the bot using the Direct Speech Client application, but I would like to talk to it from my phone, via Skype. I mean place a call to it not text. 
I know MS is deprecating the Skype and all its associated components but they are still available. 
When I place a call to the bot i hear a MS Azure message saying "You cannot talk to this bot yet but we are working on it" Is there a way I can get it to work ? 
I cannot find the documentation on Github either.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the error message, they are working on it, so currently it is not available